Are CamPemPath/ServerPemPath parameters required for MilvusClient if the Milvus cert has been imported into the java trust store?
If I want to communicate with a Milvus over TLS, can I import the pem into the default java trust store or do I have to configure the client with the CaPemPath/ServerPemPath?
IE: at the moment I'm doing this:
        ConnectParam.Builder builder = ConnectParam
                .newBuilder()
                .withHost(host)
                .withPort(port)
                .withSecure(secure);

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(caPemPath)) {
            LOGGER.info("Using ca pem path: {}", caPemPath);
            builder.withCaPemPath(caPemPath);
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(serverPemPath, serverName)) {
            LOGGER.info("Using server pem path: {} and server name: {}", serverPemPath, serverName);
            builder.withServerPemPath(serverPemPath).withServerName(serverName);
        } else if (!StringUtils.isAllBlank(serverPemPath, serverName)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Server milvus.server-pem-path and milvus.server-name must both be set or both be blank");
        }

But if I've imported Milvus' pem into the java trust store, do I need to do any of this at all? Or will it work without it?
